# Show/Hide Div During Ajax .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to show the "LoaderMain" div before the .load() and when it is all complete hide the "LoaderMain".  When I uncomment my show/hide it never displays.

```
$('#content').html('');
            //$('#LoaderMain').show();
            $("#content").load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "error") {
                var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                $("#content").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
            }

            });
            //$('#LoaderMain').hide();
```

Comment: You have to hide it in the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `$('#LoaderMain').hide();` in your callback function.

For example:

```
$('#content').html('');
$('#LoaderMain').show();
$("#content").load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        $("#content").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
    $('#LoaderMain').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since load is asynchronous, you'll need your hide() function inside the callback:

```
$('#content').html('');
$('#LoaderMain').show();
$("#content").load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        $("#content").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
    $('#LoaderMain').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#content").load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
   // Stuff 1
   $('#LoaderMain').hide();
});
// Stuff 2
```

Load is `asynchronous`, it means that the function Load will start, and **while it runs, the script continues** to stuff 2, and once the function running in background finshes, it does stuff 1. Note that if the function is very fast, stuff 1 can be done before stuff 2.

If the function was `synchronous`, stuff 1 would always be done before stuff 2.

That's why AJAX means Asynchronous JavaScript Xml, because it is made to run in background.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#content').html('');
        //$('#LoaderMain').show();
        $.ajax({
           url: "your.url",
           beforeSend: function() {
             //do something before sending the ajax, like hiding or showing that spinner
           },
           type: 'post', //or get if you prefer that
           data: "", // put parameters like ?id=1&name=something here
           success: function(data) {
             //do something after successful ajax request like $('#content').html(data);
           }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

What event are you using to load content with?

http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function

Most jquery event/ajax functions have a callback param that you can send a function to, in order to execute after the event/ajax function has complete processing.

```
$('#LoaderMain').show();
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  $('#LoaderMain').hide();
});
```